Paginated Report - The 'Value' expression for the query parameter 'xxx' refers to a non-existing report parameter
I have an issue with Paginated Report. I deleted a parameter and it's not in my report but I have this error:
The 'Value' expression for the query parameter 'xxx' refers to a non-existing report parameter 'xxx'. Letters in the names of parameters must use the correct case.
How can I resolve it?
Thank you,
I deleted all the expressions that refer to this parameter in the report, I expected the error to disappear but it's still present

Open the RDL and manually look for any reference to the parameter. If you are using Visual Studio you can just hit F7 to see the RDL, if not just open it in a decent test editor such as VS Code. If you are unsure what you need to delete, then post the section of the RDL where you find the parameter reference so somebody can guide you.

Start by re-reading the error.  A "Query Parameter" is different from a "Report Parameter".  Look at all your Datasets, the error is telling you that one of them still has a parameter that references the deleted report parameter

Yes if you want career ending platform, work with pbi paginated report builder :}
Query Designer is a bug and should be removed/commented out

I just decided to go about this illogically, because paginated doesn't make much sense to even the best developers.  I used @alanschofield's response above to search for what dataset was still showing a query parameter.  It gave me a dataset I wasn't able to see in my DataSets folder in Report Builder.
I right clicked on Datasets
Screenshot showing hidden datasets
How I can see the hidden dataset.  I opened query designer for the now unhidden dataset and low and behold, my query parameter is on that dataset.  What I learned was there are actually 4 levels of parameters so far that I know of for paginated:

Global: In the parameter section of the query designer when in design mode and first creating a dataset.  Apparently this attaches the parameter to all the datasets?
Query Parameter: can be added to the dataset properties at anypoint.
Report Parameter: can be attached to the overall report
Tablix Parameter: can be attached to a specific visual.

I haven't tested all of these yet and if you know better than me, please let us know.
